# How to set PHP timezone for cloud based web server distributed to different geographic regions?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, time-zone

I'm getting the following warning while running `php -i`:

> PHP Warning:  Unknown: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in Unknown on line 0
> ...

Our VM is hosted, and its distributed to various geographic regions. Its similar to "us-east" and "us-west" used by Amazon (though we don't use Amazon).

How do we set `date.timezone` when the server is replicated in different timezones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `date.timezone` in your `php.ini` file.

This command will locate the `php.ini` file that PHP is currently using:

```
php -i | grep 'Configuration File.* => '
```

In the example below, my `php.ini` is located at `/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.ini`, and `date.timezone` is set to `UTC`:

```
root@node2 [~]# php -i | grep 'Configuration File.* => '
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc
Loaded Configuration File => /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.ini

root@node2 [~]# grep 'date\.timezone' /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.ini
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = "UTC"
```

Comment: Thanks. We use a CentOS image, and I believe the config file is `/etc/php.ini`. What do we set it to when the VM is distributed to increase availability? If we set it to `America/New_York` for "us-east", then it will be wrong for "us-west" and `America/Los_Angeles` (and vice versa). Note that we only get a single looking glass - it appear to be a single VM to us.

Comment: @jww: Just use whatever timezone you prefer. I have mine set to `UTC` to be like Stack Exchange. If your application is timezone-sensitive for some reason, it should be programmed with `date_default_timezone_set()` set to your needs.

Comment: Best practice is to set for UTC always.  If you need to convert to other time zones, do it explicitly with each operation.  Don't rely on system defaults.

Comment: Perfect, thanks Deltik and Matt. If its a best practice, then it seems like it should be uncommented by default....